# When is it safe to cache tf.Tensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let's say we have some method `foo` we call during graph construction time that returns some `tf.Tensors` or a nested structure of them every time is called, and multiple other methods that make use of `foo`'s result. For efficiency and to avoid spamming the TF graph with unnecessary repeated operations, it might be tempting to make `foo` cache its result (to reuse the subgraph it produces) the first time is called. However, that will fail if `foo` is ever used in the context of a control flow, like `tf.cond`, `tf.map_fn` or `tf.while_loop`.

My questions are:

1. When is it safe to cache `tf.Tensor` objects in such a way that does not cause problems with control flows? Perhaps is there some way to retrieve the control flow under which a `tf.Tensor` was created (if any), store it and compare it later to see if a cached result can be reused?
2. How would the answer to the question above apply to `tf.Operations`?

(Question text updated to make clearer that `foo` creates a new set of tensors every time is called)

Comment: After posting my answer, rereading your question it seems you're confused about the separation that exists in TF between graph *construction* (i.e., `foo` defining the tensors and returning them to you) and graph *evaluation* (i.e., feeding input to the graph and computing the *value* those tensors have with the current input). You might want to read more about that, it will clarify things for you greatly

Comment: I'm well aware of the difference. I'm not suggesting to use a function that produces new tensor subgraphs every time is called because I'm getting confused with graph construction vs evaluation. Rather, I'm specifically interested in the particular situation I described during graph construction time.

Comment: Then please add a code example showing what `foo` does and what/why you'd need caching

Comment: I don't have any specific code to show you, but I can tell you that `foo` is part of a metaprogramming library that builds tensor subgraphs. It's job is precisely to create tensor structures when called.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**: TF already caches what it needs to, don't bother with it yourself.

Every time you call `sess.run([some_tensors])` TF's engine find the minimum subgraph needed to compute all tensors in `[some_tensors]` and **runs it from top to bottom** (possibly on new data, if you're not feeding it the same data).

That means, caching of results in-between `sess.run` calls is useless towards saving computation, because they will be recomputed anyway.

*If*, instead, you're concerned with having multiple tensors using the same data as input *in one call* of `sess.run`, don't worry, TF is smart enough. if you have input `A` and `B = 2*A`, `C = A + 1`, as long as you do *one* `sess.run` call as `sess.run([B,C])` `A` will be evaluated only once (and then implicitly cached by the TF engine).

Comment: That's not what I mean. I mean if `foo` is a function that produces new tensors each time is called. In that case since every result is a different subgraph (although they'd do the same) there wouldn't be any caching.

Comment: Which takes me back to my comment to your question. Do you have clear the distinction between tensor *definition* and *evaluation*? (Sorry if this sounds like a dumb question but since you don't post `foo`'s code I don't know what you do with those tensors)